# OpenVPN - no internet access

Tags: openvpn

I installed OpenVPN using this tutorial: https://blog.ssdnodes.com/blog/tutorial-installing-openvpn-on-ubuntu-16-04/

I can connect to VPN from my computer but there is no internet connection. After I connect into  VPN I have notification: client1 is connected, IP address 10.8.0.6.

In logs I see this warnings:

```
2021-10-08 09:40:10 NOTE: --user option is not implemented on Windows
2021-10-08 09:40:10 NOTE: --group option is not implemented on Windows
2021-10-08 09:40:10 WARNING: Compression for receiving enabled. Compression has been used in the past to break encryption. Sent packets are not compressed unless "allow-compression yes" is also set.
2021-10-08 09:40:10 DEPRECATED OPTION: --cipher set to 'AES-256-CBC' but missing in --data-ciphers (AES-256-GCM:AES-128-GCM). Future OpenVPN version will ignore --cipher for cipher negotiations. Add 'AES-256-CBC' to --data-ciphers or change --cipher 'AES-256-CBC' to --data-ciphers-fallback 'AES-256-CBC' to silence this warning.
```

What did I do wrong? Is there anything I should do that is missing in the manual?

I'm using VPS from Bonsai from VMHaus - I sent ticket but they told me that they are not blocking vpn and can not help me.

Comment: You even didn't set up  a firewall for openvpn. Then routing problem is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an instance
2. At least, open port TCP 22 and UDP 1194 outside your instance at the control panel of your instance provider
3. SSH into your instance and change the user to root using `sudo su root`
4. create a file using nano `nano filename.sh`
5. Make the file executable using `chmod +x filename.sh`
6. Paste the following code into the file.
7. Execute the file using `./filename.sh`
8. The server will setup automatically, you need to press `yes` and `enter` to continue. Finally the machine will restart.
9. Donwload your config file from `/etc/openvpn/client/client.ovpn` and try to connect VPN.

```
#!/bin/bash

#Tested on Debian 10. Updata on 2021-10-09; Author: Yuan Lin
#Notes: 1. Switch to root to configure
#       e.g. sudo su root
#   2. Change the file to be excutable before run it.
#       e.g. chmod +x openvpn.sh
#   3. Open port 1194/udp at the control panel of your cloud provider.

#1. Update program list and upgrade all programs.
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade

#2. Download openvpn easyrsa and ufw firewall
apt-get install openvpn easy-rsa ufw

#3. Copy the sample file to configure your own vpn file.
gunzip -c /usr/share/doc/openvpn/examples/sample-config-files/server.conf.gz > /etc/openvpn/server.conf
cp /usr/share/doc/openvpn/examples/sample-config-files/client.conf /etc/openvpn/client/client.ovpn

#4. Configure server vpn file
#nano /etc/openvpn/server.conf

sed -i -e 's/dh2048.pem/dh.pem/g' /etc/openvpn/server.conf
sed -i -e 's/;push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"/push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"/g' /etc/openvpn/server.conf

#Force the client to use only DNS providers assigned by VPN configuration.
echo "" >> /etc/openvpn/server.conf
echo 'push "block-outside-dns"' >> /etc/openvpn/server.conf

#Use Google DNS.
sed -i -e 's/;push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"/push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"/g' /etc/openvpn/server.conf
sed -i -e 's/;push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"/push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"/g' /etc/openvpn/server.conf
sed -i -e 's/;user nobody/user nobody/g' /etc/openvpn/server.conf
sed -i -e 's/;group nogroup/group nogroup/g' /etc/openvpn/server.conf
#Allow multi users to connect with the same client fiel.
sed -i -e 's/;duplicate-cn/duplicate-cn/g' /etc/openvpn/server.conf
#Send ping every 5 secs and reconnect after 10 secs if no response.
sed -i -e 's/keepalive 10 120/keepalive 5 10/g' /etc/openvpn/server.conf

#5. IP Forward
#nano /etc/sysctl.conf
sed -i -e 's/#net.ipv4.ip_forward=1/net.ipv4.ip_forward=1/g' nano /etc/sysctl.conf
#nano /etc/default/ufw
sed -i -e 's/DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="DROP"/DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="ACCEPT"/g' /etc/default/ufw

#6. Lead VPN netword to go through the local network.
#nano /etc/ufw/before.rules
cat <<EOT >> /etc/ufw/before.rules
*nat :POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/8 -o ens4 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
EOT

#7. Open the firewall
ufw allow 22/tcp
ufw allow 1194/udp
ufw enable

#8. Build the openvpn server

openvpn --genkey --secret /etc/openvpn/ta.key
/usr/share/easy-rsa/easyrsa init-pki
/usr/share/easy-rsa/easyrsa gen-dh
/usr/share/easy-rsa/easyrsa build-ca nopass
/usr/share/easy-rsa/easyrsa build-server-full server nopass
#Copy server crendential files to openvpn server directory.
cp $PWD/pki/ca.crt /etc/openvpn
cp $PWD/pki/issued/server.crt /etc/openvpn
cp $PWD/pki/private/server.key /etc/openvpn
cp $PWD/pki/dh.pem /etc/openvpn


#9. Start openvpn server
systemctl start openvpn@server
service openvpn start



#10. Build the openvpn client and repeat the process to create additional clients.
/usr/share/easy-rsa/easyrsa build-client-full myclient nopass
#nano /etc/openvpn/client/client.ovpn
ip_address="$(curl icanhazip.com)"
sed -i -e "s/remote my-server-1 1194/remote ${ip_address} 1194/g" /etc/openvpn/client/client.ovpn
sed -i -e 's/;user nobody/user nobody/g' /etc/openvpn/client/client.ovpn
sed -i -e 's/;group nogroup/group nogroup/g' /etc/openvpn/client/client.ovpn
sed -i -e 's/ca ca.crt/;ca ca.crt/g' /etc/openvpn/client/client.ovpn
sed -i -e 's/cert client.crt/;cert client.crt/g' /etc/openvpn/client/client.ovpn
sed -i -e 's/key client.key/;key client.key/g' /etc/openvpn/client/client.ovpn
sed -i -e 's/tls-auth ta.key 1/;tls-auth ta.key 1/g' /etc/openvpn/client/client.ovpn

#Add client crendential files to a single .ovpn file.
echo "" >> /etc/openvpn/client/client.ovpn
echo "key-direction 1" >> /etc/openvpn/client/client.ovpn
echo "<ca>" >> /etc/openvpn/client/client.ovpn
cat $PWD/pki/ca.crt >> /etc/openvpn/client/client.ovpn
echo "</ca>" >> /etc/openvpn/client/client.ovpn
echo "<cert>" >> /etc/openvpn/client/client.ovpn
cat $PWD/pki/issued/myclient.crt >> /etc/openvpn/client/client.ovpn
echo "</cert>" >> /etc/openvpn/client/client.ovpn
echo "<key>" >> /etc/openvpn/client/client.ovpn
cat $PWD/pki/private/myclient.key >> /etc/openvpn/client/client.ovpn
echo "</key>" >> /etc/openvpn/client/client.ovpn
echo "<tls-auth>" >> /etc/openvpn/client/client.ovpn
cat /etc/openvpn/ta.key >> /etc/openvpn/client/client.ovpn
echo "</tls-auth>" >> /etc/openvpn/client/client.ovpn

#12. reboot the server computer to activate the configuration.
reboot
```